# Strange lines appear on pcolormesh in basemap when using a nonzero alpha value

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

When plotting data using pcolormesh on a basemap projection (or a cartopy projection) I notice strange lines appear when I set the alpha value to less than 1.

Example code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

dpp =1 # degrees per pixel
lons = np.arange(-180,180+dpp,dpp)
lats = -1*np.arange(-90,90+dpp,dpp)

m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0)
data = np.random.random((np.size(lats), np.size(lons)))
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(lons, lats)

im = m.pcolormesh(x, y, x, latlon=False, cmap='RdBu')
#im = m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, latlon=True, cmap='RdBu')

m.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

The output shows strange lines appearing:

[image]

If I instead set alpha=1 the lines disappear and the behavior is as expected:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get pcolormesh to work with a nonzero alpha value?

Answer (score 5):

Use `pcolor` instead of `pcolormesh`, it is a bit slower but it does a better job with handling rasterized output. Be sure to set `snap = True`, this will align the grid to the pixels.

#### Example

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-180,180), np.arange(90,-90,-1))

im = plt.pcolor(lons, lats, lons, cmap='RdBu', alpha=0.5, snap=True)

cbar = plt.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

This should work with [`mpl_toolkits.basemap`](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.pcolor) as well.

[image]

The lines in the colorbar are caused by the [open issue #1188](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188), as far as I know there is not a work around known which does not involve manually creating the colorbar.

Comment: I reproduced the figure of yours above (although there are still strange lines on the colorbar). However, when using basemap or cartopy I still get strange lines. So it still seems to be an issue when using a curved projection, like the robinson projection.

Comment: Using the following lines in your script still had strange lines appear: import cartopy.crs as ccrs   ____   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())  _____  im = ax.pcolor(lons, lats, lons, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='RdBu', alpha=0.5, snap=True)

Comment: How can I manually create the colorbar with the proper alpha value?

Comment: @ricitron My apologies, you would be using a curved projection. `pcolor` and `pcolormesh` will both be insufficient there, you will have to `imshow` I believe

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a global map, I got it to work using imshow instead of pcolor or pcolormesh:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

plt.clf()

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-180,180), np.arange(90,-90,-1))

im = ax.imshow(lons, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='RdBu', alpha=0.5, extent=[-180,180,-90,90])

cbar = plt.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_alpha(0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

There is still the issue with the colorbar however.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer the issue with the color bar is subject to an [open issue on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188) without an existing workaround short of full manual handling of the color bar creation. Matplotlib simply doesn’t handle the alpha correctly for colorbars

Comment: Is there an example for manually creating the desired colorbar? i.e., using a matplotlib color scale and setting alpha=0.5 for a colorbar